# Counting Days from today start with 1 insted of 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working PHP code that reads the date from the database compares it with today's date, and prints the result. All working great, but when the recorded date is today and the code compares it with today the result is 0. How can I change the result to 1 and still count the days correctly?

```
      <?php include 'dbconnect.php';?>
  <?php 
     $sql = "SELECT startdate 
          FROM counter
     ORDER BY id 
     DESC limit 1";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $recoredDate = $row["startdate"];
        
     
     // get todays date
     $today = new DateTime();
     
     // set the date to compare
     $date = new DateTime($recoredDate);
     // counting from midnight, set the hour, minute and seconds to zero
     
     // calcualate the difference between the two dates
     $diff = $today->diff($date);
     
     
     $week = floor($today->diff($date)->days/7+1);
     
       }
     } else {
       echo "<h4><b>No ongoing count</b></h4>";
     }
     ?>
  <div id="dw"align=center>
     <span class="block p-2 bg-grey">
     <h2> <?php echo $diff->format('Day %a');?></h2>
     </span>
     <span class="block p-2 bg-grey">
     <h2> <?php echo "Week $week";?></h2>
     </span>     
 </div>
```

Comment: Compare to yesterday? `$today = new DateTime('yesterday');`

Comment: perhaps just change the way you display it? `<h2><?= $week ? $week : ‘Current' ?><</h2>`

Comment: @Dharman unfortunately yesterday it's not a good solution as when hit 00:00 o'clock prints 0 again.

Comment: You want to know how to add (or subtract) 1?

Comment: @Strawberry I want to count from 1 like 1,2,3,4,5. instead of 0,1,2,3,4